# How to detect a newly created file in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way to detect when a file is created or modified or downloaded in the android phone? I checked the available intents, but none of them are related to files. I am working on the broadcast receiver and couldnt figure out a way to detect a new file creation. Can someone please help?

Comment: u can check count of storage and incase it is increament then u can list all the files...

Answer (score 0):

use [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html)...

```
public class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver {

    public MyFileObserver(String path) {
        super(path);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        switch (event) {
        case DELETE:
            // file deleted
            break;
        case ACCESS:
            // file accessed;
            break;
        case MODIFY:
            // file modified;
            break;
        case OPEN:
            // file opened
            break;
         // see documentation for available events
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

sample usage:

```
    MyFileObserver fileObserver = new MyFileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    fileObserver.startWatching();
```